# How does "dragon branch ads" get installed on a PC?

Tags: malware

This annoying app called "dragon branch ads" was installed on my PC and I have no idea how or *what installed it on my PC*. My question is.. **Does anyone know how "dragon branch ads" may have been installed on my PC?**

I also read through the question [How can I remove malicious spyware, malware, viruses or rootkits from my PC](https://superuser.com/questions/100360/how-can-i-remove-malicious-spyware-malware-viruses-or-rootkits-from-my-pc/) but could not find any mention of "dragon branch adds" or what third party app **"installs"** "dragon branch adds"

Steven's answer has instructions on how to remove "dragon branch adds" from a PC. It doesn't directly answer my question but did point me in the direction of a YouTube downloader program.  After looking further into this, I think, don't know with certainty, but I think this “Free YouTube Downloader” program published by HOW Inc is the application that also installed "dragon branch adds" on my PC.

I think this Free YouTube Downloader is the culprit, two days ago I manually removed "dragon branch adds', last night I uninstalled the “Free YouTube Downloader” and I have not seen “dragon branch adds" since so..  I do not know for sure that this "Free YouTube Downloader" also installed "dragon branch adds" but it sure seems like thats where it came from

[image]

Comment: Is your objective to get rid of it or to find out how it got there?

Comment: No, my question is not how to remove it.  My question is is how did "dragon branch adds" get installed on my PC?

Comment: The Q&A model of Super User relies on the structure of questions being just questions and solutions being answers.  Incorporating an answer into the question messes with that.  Since the addition just confirms information in Steven's answer, it would be better to post that information in a comment there.  But glad you got your answer.

Comment: BTW, the answer was closed as a duplicate even though your comments and edit now indicate that it actually isn't.  However, what you're asking requires people to guess at how some malware ended up on your computer.  Unfortunately, that type of question doesn't have a definitive answer, so it would likely be closed on that basis.

Answer (score 6):

According to the following page, Dragon Branch Ads is often installed by the installer of other third-party utilities such as VLC player.

The page also describes the removal process.

http://malwareprotectioncenter.com/2015/05/03/dragon-branch/

EDIT: The following page lists several applications which may install Dragon Branch Ads, including the "Youtube Downloader HD" you mentioned.

http://www.malwarekillers.com/dragon-branch-adware-removal/

Comment: Yeah i was able to manually remove it. Just can't nail down what "third party app" may have snuck this fn thing in.  I recently installed a "YouTube down-loader, Battlefield 4, maybe a chrome extension, hell I don't know.  I reckon I'll keep an eye out for what may be trying to put this thing on my PC

Comment: According to another page (added to my post), Youtube Downloader HD does install Dragon Branch Ads.

Comment: It's odd, I can't see where the URL in your 2nd post mentions the youtube down loader, I believe you though ;-)

Comment: It's under Step 1 of the Manual Dragon Branch Removal.